# This code gives me a segmentation fault(Core Dump). I don't quite understand why?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{ int Element; struct Node* Next;};

int main(){

struct Node *header=NULL;
struct Node *ptr;
```

Creating the linked list here

```
ptr=header;
ptr->Next=NULL;
int x;
printf("Input the elements. End with zero.\n");
scanf("%d", &x);

int c=0;//Counter
```

Reading each element

```
while(x!=0)
{
  if(c==0)
  { header=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));    
    ptr=header;
    ptr->Element=x;
    c++;
    scanf("%d", &x);
   }
  else
  { ptr->Next=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
ptr=ptr->Next;
ptr->Element=x;
ptr->Next=NULL;
c++;
scanf("%d", &x);
   }
}

printf("/n");

struct Node *temp;

if(header==NULL)
printf("List is empty.\n");
else
{
for(temp=header;temp!=NULL;temp=temp->Next)
{printf("%d\n", temp->Element);}
}
```

Here I'm printing the List.

```
}
```

Also, I really don't understand segmentation faults at all. Why does it just say "Segmentation fault: Core dump" rather than giving us more details?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Then learn how to **use the debugger** (`gdb`). Understand what is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: step through in your debugger.

Comment: Read also wikipages on [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space). BTW you want `printf("\n")` not `printf("/n")` !

Answer (score 1):

You set ptr to NULL:

```
ptr=header;
```

Then you try to dereference NULL. This line will crash:

```
ptr->Next=NULL;
```

Fix your logic.

Comment: The answer is correct, but I am not sure it is really helpful for a newbie. The OP (Steve) should have found that by himself.

Comment: Yes, please don't answer such questions. SO is completely flodded by such questions, which undermines the goal of this site to be a searchable knowledge base.

Comment: Yeah - nearly always linked-lists, nearly always bad dereferencing, nearly always no attempt to debug at all.